# How to download snapshot artifacts from AWS S3 Repository?

Tags: maven-3

I have uploaded snapshots to AWS S3 for repository management. How can I download snapshot artifacts from aws s3 repository?

I have provided server details in setting.xml

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>repo.teamed.io</id>
      <username>AKIAI9NNNJD5D7X4TUVA</username>
      <password>t5tZQCwuaRhmlOXfbGE5aTBMFw34iFyxfCEr32av</password>
    </server>
    [...]
  </servers>
  [...]
</settings>
```

I am able to upload artifacts to S3. But not able to download it.

I tried it through

```
<mirror>
  <id>repo.teamed.io</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>s3://repo.teamed.io/snapshots/</url>
</mirror>
```